# Are tables still bad for layout?

Tags: html, css

I just wasted 4 hours trying to align some text vertically while avoiding the use of tables.

I tried to use the approach outlined here http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html which seems to be one of the recommended solutions here on the stack.

However, given some of the structure and CSS I need to use (floating/percent widths/absolute positioning of elements within elements/etc...), in order to maintain a responsive layout while achieving the result I need, I was unable to make the supplied solution work due to one gotcha or another.

Ultimately I had to wrap it up and just use a table so as to not lose too much more time.

So my question is, should we still avoid tables for (some) layout at all costs, or has this view evolved at all given the frequency of the stated dilemma and the complexity of todays layouts?

**EDIT:**

**WHICH ONE LOOKS LIKE THE HACK TO YOU? CAN YOU SPOT IT?**

This is a hack, the above link even states that! (Search for the word "hack" on the page.)

```
<div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
```

This is the way html was designed to be used and it always works!

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Text
```

**What looks cleaner?! Don't be fooled! Use your own mind!**

Comment: There is *a lot* of documentation about centering vertically out htere. One of my favorite last read about it: http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/easily-center-text-vertically-with-svg/

Comment: W3C does not propose a solution, they just cause a problem, browsers already supply a solution but we have this antiquated view of layout. Beware the trolls, they are everywhere and even control the stack!

Comment: Your edit/comment comes off as arrogant, which won't win you any favors.  The W3C says "use CSS".  There are about 20 "common" different techniques for controlling a document's layout.  Table elements have a specific meaning to assistive technologies, that's the reason the W3C strongly urges web authors not to use them for layout purposes.

Comment: Maybe they should give us an updated way to use tables (that have been around forever and work) nicely with assistive technologies. That's the right way, the W3C are the ones taking the easy way out, trying to make up for mistakes after the fact instead of fixing the root problem. Bottom line, tables work, use them and advance them. OR ADD MORE SENSIBLE LAYOUT FEATURES TO THE CSS SPEC! Might as well while we're butchering the web right now.

Comment: Look, you can argue with me on a number of fronts here, but where it comes to the rendering of content, you can't tell me that the table method doesn't work. Reopen the question and create the opportunity for some real answers on this. THIS IS THE PLACE FOR THIS TYPE OF QUESTION, this is where some of the greatest minds come to share ideas one way or another, let the process happen. I know the stack rules, but you have got to see the potential here for a moment of clarity on this issue, especially given the impact it's had in time and money for so many people.

Comment: **Last comment: WEB LAYOUT CAN BE BETTER!**

Comment: vertical centering has always been a PITA in css. check out the new flexbox. <div style='display:flex;width:500px;height:500px;background:red;align-items: center;justify-content:center;'>Hi, Ma!</div>

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, should we still avoid tables for (some) layout at all costs

Yes

> or has this view evolved at all given the frequency of the stated dilemma and the complexity of todays layouts?

The view has evolved given increased browser support for more CSS.